# Что происходит в методе newInstance?

Tags: java, vert.x

В классе Router фреймворка vert.x есть такой конструктор и метод:

```
public class Router {

  final io.vertx.ext.web.Router delegate;

  public Router(io.vertx.ext.web.Router delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public Object getDelegate() {
    return delegate;
  }

  /**
   * Create a router
   * @param vertx the Vert.x instance
   * @return the router
   */
  public static Router router(Vertx vertx) { 
    Router ret= Router.newInstance(io.vertx.ext.web.Router.router((io.vertx.core.Vertx) vertx.getDelegate()));
    return ret;
  }
```

в строчке непонятно что происходит:

```
newInstance(io.vertx.ext.web.Router.router((io.vertx.core.Vertx) vertx.getDelegate()));
```

вернее, результат примерно ясен-он берет инстанс-делегат vertex.но как это происходит и какой именно инстанс он берет?

```
io.vertx.ext.web.Router
io.vertx.core.Vertx
```

эти строки-подключение пакетов-классов vert.x core и vert.x web. я с таким синтаксисом раньше не сталкивался(чтобы это прописывалось в теле метода.обычно все подключается в верхней части кода, например так эти строки-подключение пакетов-классов vert.x core и vert.x web. я с таким синтаксисом раньше не сталкивался,обычно все подключается в верхней части кода,например так import io.vertx.rxjava.core.Vertx;).Объясните пожалуйста как понимать данный синтаксис?и что по порядку происходит в методе `newInstance()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все достаточно просто. Вызывается статический метод из класса `Router.router()` с указанием полного пути до него `io.vertx.core`. Дальше происходит кастинг объекта `Vertx` с полным указание пути до него `io.vertx.core`. Это сделано из-за повторяющихся названий классов.